# React native app authenticity

Tags: android, react-native

How does one verify in our server that the android app is from an official source, say downloaded through google play? Since you can just basically extract android js bundle from the apk.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on exactly what you are trying to achieve you can look into App Licensing https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html